# PHP - Call SoapClient with header, and returns fatal error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapheader

I am still very new to use php to call the SoapClient. Recently I have a project which I need to call the API from .net using web service SOAP.

I won't able to see the actual XML code of the web service URL provided as it requires header to access, therefore test via POSTMAN, it works well.

However, it doesn't work when using php to call their web service on the localhost server (XAMPP), (other web service address work fine on the code below), not sure where it goes wrong:

```
  $Auth = array(

    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
    'X-RW-Auth-Token' => '4f931e62-d8c8-439b-a4d7-0c29fc0e3dbe'

);

$client = new SoapClient("https://licensed-ws.ricewarnerdigital.com/process/RiskEngine/v1.0/EndPoint.asmx?wsdl");

$header = new SoapHeader(url,null, $Auth,false);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$param = array(
    'RR_AgeNext' => '30',
    'RR_TermSI' => '1000000',
    'RR_TPDSI' => '3000000',
    'RR_AnyOwn' => 'A'
);

$GetResponse = $client->GetQuotationsForParameters($param);
```

### Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '...' : failed to load external entity "..." in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/quote-tool/ricewarner_api.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/quote-tool/ricewarner_api.php(11): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://license...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/quote-tool/ricewarner_api.php on line 11

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your WSDL.  I cannot access the URL in your code.

Comment: It's the only URL provided by the API company, the support said that it has   to send with the header info in order to access...if you use postman, with the header provided, it will work but not on the php. Thanx

Comment: My first guess is that your SOAP envelope has a problem.  This is why I asked for the WSDL.

Comment: The SOAP envelope itself has no problem, because tested on the postman it responsed. It has to do with header X-RW-Auth-Token and Content-Type that need to associate with the envelope together post the request. but not sure why the code isn't working...

Comment: Please post your `<soapenv:Header>` tag.  I'm afraid without this, we cannot help you.

Comment: What I have right now is the <soap:body> sample which was provided by the API, https://jsfiddle.net/7fz0hxco/

Comment: Read what your error says.  PHP cannot even load the WSDL file.  I could not access this from a browser either.  I do think you have other problems, but first you need to load the WSDL.  Try downloading it and reading it locally if you can.

Comment: Hi I just obtain another WSDL from the API company https://riskengine.ricewarnerdigital.com/Service/EndPoint.asmx - the errors is now : Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /home/lifeinsu/public_html/ricewarner_api.php:28 - I have add 'numberOfyears' in the param array as well

Comment: First thing I see:

    $header = new SoapHeader(url,null, $Auth,false);

What ist url? Where did you define it?

Comment: - I only could put one URL in the quetion, that's why I put the URL text it actually should be http://ricewarner.com, however, the provider has given me another WSDL link riskengine.ricewarnerdigital.com/Service/EndPoint.asmx , and its not necessarily need header anymore...but still coming out error in xampp but works fine on https server

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it to work, eventually the SoapClient couldn't work with the web service which contain licensing layer so I have to use CURl to call. Below is the code:

class GetPremiumData{

```
        public function doXMLCurl($url,$postXML){

        $CURL = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postXML); 
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','X-RW-Auth-Token: apiToken'));
        curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $xmlResponse = curl_exec($CURL);

        return $xmlResponse;
    }

}
```